# Group data based on conditional Statement

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a data which looks like this as shown below:

| Test_ID1 | Output |
| --- | --- |
| A | M |
| A | M |
| A | M |
| A | F |
| B | F |
| B | F |
| B | F |
| C | M |
| C | F |

I want to create a new column in this table or new table such that it will groupby based on Test_ID1 and if Count of (M) is greater than (F) then It should display M else if Count of (F) it should display (M) and if count of (M) = Count of (F) then it should display as "P". So my final output would appear like this.

| Test_ID1 | Final_Output |
| --- | --- |
| A | M |
| B | F |
| C | P |

Please help me with the above issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First write a measure to calculate desired output. Then use that measure in Summarize function to get actual output.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I would add to this solution that unless actually persisting the summarized table in the data model is required, this is not a good practice. All additional table entities in DAX must be calculated at query time and will be a detriment on performance. In this small data model it is obviously not important, but as a developer it is highly recommended to carefully weigh pros and cons of various ways of handling the data. If the goal is to provide a visual with the desired output, it is not required to persist a calculated column *or* a calculated table to the model - a measure is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

As a **Calculated Column** in your existing table:

```
=
VAR ThisID = Table1[Test_ID1]
VAR MaleCount =
    COUNTROWS (
        FILTER (
            Table1,
            Table1[Test_ID1] = ThisID
                && Table1[Output] = "M"
        )
    )
VAR FemaleCount =
    COUNTROWS (
        FILTER (
            Table1,
            Table1[Test_ID1] = ThisID
                && Table1[Output] = "F"
        )
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        MaleCount > FemaleCount,
        "M",
        IF (
            FemaleCount > MaleCount,
            "F",
            "P"
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

While you ask for a calculated column, here is a measure solution to be used together with your `Table[Test_ID1]` column in e.g. a table visual:

```
Final_Output = 
VAR _m = COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( 'Table' , 'Table'[Output] = "M" ) )
VAR _total = COUNTROWS ( 'Table' )
RETURN
    SWITCH ( 
        TRUE () ,
        _m > _total / 2 , "M" , 
        _m = _total / 2 , "P" ,
        "F"
    )
```